# How can I increase range of x-axis in probability density plot even If I have no data for that?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

Actually I am trying to plot density plot in python. I want range for -1 to 1 however I know I don't have values in my data set beyond -0.6 and 0.6. But is there any way where I can plot just zero for all the values beyond -0.6 an 0.6. In short I want to increase range of my plot to make it consistent.

[image]

So far I am using this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import seaborn as sns

data_Pre1 = pd.read_csv("new errors.csv")


for s in data_Pre1.columns:
    data_Pre1[s].plot(kind='density', sharey = True)
#plt.title("Disk Galaxies", fontsize = 18)
plt.xlabel("$E_i$", fontsize = 40)
plt.ylabel('Density', fontsize = 40)
plt.xlim(-1,1)
plt.legend(fontsize =25)
plt.xticks(size = 15)
plt.yticks(size = 15)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution is based on passing *ind* parameter to *plot*.
It specifies evaluation points for the estimated PDF.
As the number of points I chose *700* but you can change it as you wish,
e.g. to get more smooth curves.
For consistency, pass just the same border values to *plt.xlim(...)*.

So change respective lines of your code to:

```
minX, maxX = (-1.0, 1.0)
for s in data_Pre1.columns:
    data_Pre1[s].plot(kind='density', sharey=True, ind=np.linspace(minX, maxX, 700))
plt.xlim(minX, maxX)
```

Other possible correction is that instead of explicit looping over columns
of your DataFrame, you can call your plot for the **whole** DataFrame:

```
data_Pre1.plot.density(ind=np.linspace(minX, maxX, 700))
```

## Edit

The evaluation points specified with *ind* need not be evenly spaced
throughout the whole *x* axis "wanted" range.

If you are sure about both "limits" of *x* axis "discovered" by the
plotting function (you wrote *-0.6* and *0.6*), you can generate *ind*
as densely spaced points **only** in this range and then:

- prepend it with a **single** point - your "wanted" lower *x* limit,
- append it with also a **single** point - your "wanted" upper *x* limit.

So you can change your code to:

```
minX, maxX = (-1.0, 1.0)      # "Wanted" x axis limits
minSrc, maxSrc = (-0.6, 0.6)  # X axis limits "discovered" in your data
nPoints = 700                 # How many estimation points in the "discovered" range
ind = np.concatenate(([minX], np.linspace(minSrc, maxSrc, nPoints), [maxX]))
data_Pre1.plot.density(ind=ind)
plt.xlim(minX, maxX)
```

Comment: I have tried with 100. It works but curve is not smooth. I have total 16000 values in the dataset. So, how much should I use to get smooth curve?

Comment: The number of values is not very important here. Try with higher values (e.g. *200*, *300*, ...) and look at the resulting curves whether the are smooth enough. The default number of points is *1000*, so maybe you should take just *1000*?